# Why does Int32.Equals(Int16) return true where the reverse doesn't?

Tags: c#, .net

The .Net Equals() returns different results, though we are comparing the same values. Can someone explain me why that is the case?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int16 a = 1;
        Int32 b = 1;

        var test1 = b.Equals(a);    //true
        var test2 = a.Equals(b);    //false
    }
}
```

Has it got to do anything with the range of the types we are comparing against?

Comment: Something with implicit casting from int16 to int32 and an `object` overload for when no such cast is possible. Trying to find the relevant Q&A...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Int32` has an [`Equals(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf6tw08e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload and `Int16` can be implicity converted to an equivalent `Int32`. With this overload, it's now comparing two 32-bit integers, checks for value equality, and naturally returns `true`.

`Int16` has its own [`Equals(Int16)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de7hf7c3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method overload, but there is no implicit conversion from an `Int32` to an `Int16` (because you can have values that are out of range for a 16-bit integer). Thus the type system ignores this overload and reverts to the [`Equals(Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs113b2h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload. Its documentation reports:

> true if obj is an instance of Int16 and equals the value of this
>   instance; otherwise, false.

But, the value we're passing in, while it "equals the value of this instance" (`1 == 1`) it's *not* an instance of `Int16` as it's an `Int32`.

---

The equivalent code for the `b.Equals(a)` that you have would look like this:

```
Int16 a = 1;
Int32 b = 1;

Int32 a_As_32Bit = a; //implicit conversion from 16-bit to 32-bit

var test1 = b.Equals(a_As_32Bit); //calls Int32.Equals(Int32)
```

Now it's clear we're comparing both numbers as 32-bit integers.

The equivalent code for the `a.Equals(b)` would look this:

```
Int16 a = 1;
Int32 b = 1;

object b_As_Object = b; //treats our 16-bit integer as a System.Object

var test2 = a.Equals(b_As_Object); //calls Int16.Equals(Object)
```

Now it's clear we're calling a different equality method. Internally, that equality method is doing more or less this:

```
Int16 a = 1;
Int32 b = 1;

object b_As_Object = b;

bool test2;
if (b_As_Object is Int16) //but it's not, it's an Int32
{
    test2 = ((Int16)b_As_Object) == a;
}
else
{
    test2 = false; //and this is where your confusing result is returned
}
```

Comment: So why does the .Net do an implicit conversion in the first case, `Int32.Equals(Int16)`? Is that good?

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash: Yes, it's generally a good thing. `Int32` encompasses all possible values of `Int16`, so it's handy to be able to easily feed 16-bit integers in wherever something is calling for a 32-bit integer. The range of a 32-bit is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 whereas a 16-bit is only -32,768 to 32,767. You can't do the reverse because how would you treat the number 1,000,000 as a 16-bit integer? For reference, here are the numeric [implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) and [explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yht2cx7b.aspx) conversions.

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash: That said, of course you can still do the reverse conversion (because `1` as a 32-bit integer can still be represented in 16-bit) via an explicit conversion: `Int32 a = 1; Int16 b = (Int16)a;`. This will work at runtime if the number fits into the 16-bit size, but if it's outside the range it will throw an error. Here is some reading on conversions in C#: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Comment: thanks @ChrisSinclair

Answer (score 2):

You should use equality operator (`==`) because `Equals()` methods are not supposed to return true for objects of different types.
Also there is no type in your code inherited from both `short` and `int`. change to this returns true:

```
var test2 = a == b.Id;    //true
```

Comment: The question is not "How can I make it return true", but why `int16.Equals(int32)` doesn't return `true`.

Comment: you are right. But this show difference between `equality operator` and `Equals`.